# No response to HTTP requests sent via cURL to certain hosts

Tags: php, http, curl

cURL (via PHP) on my local machine is working fine, but on a production server, I am getting no response when connecting to some hosts, while others are working Fine. Further, I can use wget to download from the hosts curl cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be - my server is on IPv6, and it cURL is trying to make connections via IPv6, to hosts who do not support it. The solution for PHP is:

```
CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE = CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4
```

command line:

```
curl -4 http://host-that-does-not-have-an-ipv6-address
```

Also if you are using a SOCKS proxy, in PHP, the following may help:

```
CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE = 7
```